Generic Intersection of Submanifolds
This is the geometric version of this linear algebra question.
Given submanifolds $N_1\cdots N_n$ of $M$ and $p\in M$, show that the map induced by inclusions
$f:\bigoplus_{i}T_pN_i\to(T_pM)^n/{\Delta}$ is surjective where $\Delta$ is diagonal of the product tangent space iff there is a decomposition in a neighborhood of $p$: $U=L_1\times \cdots \times L_n,p=(p_1\cdots p_i)$ so that $N_i=L_1\times \cdots\times p_i\times\cdots\times L_n$.
Is it true that we can choose some coordinate so that $N_1,\cdots,N_n$ all become hyperplanes? If this is true then the claim follws from linear algebra version.
I think this might involve some cleve use of implicit function theorem, but I cannot figure out how.
